# How do I write a better coffeescript class for a ngAnimation hook

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm writing a bit of code to encapsulate an angular animation into a coffeescript class. I think it's ugly. any suggestion to make it shine?

I don't like the fact that I have to create the object first and return an object with **addClass** and **removeClass** pointing it indirectly to my instance methods.

html used

```
<div ng-hide="..." class="message">...</div>
```

the ugly code

```
class MessageAnimation
  constructor: () ->
    console.log 'MessageAnimation:init'

  animation_up: (element, cl, done) ->
    element.removeClass cl
    element.velocity 'slideUp',
      duration: 500
      complete: () ->
        element.addClass cl
        done()
    return

  animation_down: (element, cl, done) ->
    element.velocity 'slideDown',
      duration: 500
      complete: () ->
        done()
    return

angular.module('some_nice_app').animation '.message', () ->
 @messageAnimation = new MessageAnimation()
 return {
   addClass: @messageAnimation.animation_up
   removeClass: @messageAnimation.animation_down
 }
```

....but maybe I don't need a class after all, because it's only instantiated ones. what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably do not need to create a class unless you need to create state you need to reference from other methods. AKA, In the example you've given there is no, `this.` reference in your methods. You can use classes as a convenient way to namespace methods, but in that case they are no different than a normal JS object. example:

```
class MessageAnimation
  # the prefix of @ places this method on the prototype as a 'static' method
  @animation_up: ->



angular.module('some_nice_app').animation '.message', () ->
  addClass: MessageAnimation.animation_up # note: CS will automatically return the object, your use of return is redundant but some people prefer to be explicit.
```

Comment: thanks. using statics didn't cross my mind yesterday. like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

or use the old fashion way:

```
angular.module('manor_app').animation '.message', ->
  animation_up =  (element, cl, done) ->
   ...

  animation_down = (element, cl, done) ->
   ...

  addClass: animation_up
  removeClass: animation_down
```

i think i find the static class one more readable